# pre-allocate memory to aligned byte like aligned_alloc in c or c++

Tags: c++, c, memory-alignment, avx, avx512

512 intrinsic I need to align memory to a 64 byte boundary in c or c++ [guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=173,6015,6015,5463,5436,5522,5352,2386,2389,4072,5340,5310,5434,5342,5310,3267,3284,4609,4601,3934,3925,3975,3934,3222,3925,5340,5310,5342,5434,5436,5463,5465,5522,5552,233,233,5552,5520,5554,5554,5554,3345,3428,4394,5554,5890,6149,6151,6172,4565,2553,2549,2541,2537,2577,2581,2591,2603,6151,6172,2396,435,446,4175,4176,5148,5150,3290,3801,5554,5552,5522,5520,5465,5463,5436,5434,5342,5340,5310,5308,5308,5150,3932,3934,3925,3975,4003,4005,681,6072,2986,3425,3413,3374,3371,3013,3022,2986,3304,3304&text=_mm512_load_epi32)

I can do that with `char *ptr = aligned_alloc(64, size);` [aligned_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc)

But i want to do something like `char ptr[size] = {0};` aligned to a block

Comment: Use C++11 / C11 `alignas(64)`

Comment: (In C11, `#include <stdalign.h>` to define it as `_Alignas`)